# onclick action for a field in jEasyUI

Tags: datagrid, jquery-easyui

Using jEasyUI, I want to perform a Master/Detail lookup from a table.

**Master**

```
10
12
```

**Detail**

```
A       B
----    -----
10 10,  Cat,20
10 10,  Cow,2
10 10,  Chicken,11
12 12,  Pig,2
```

When I click on `10` in the **Master table** `dg1` above, I want **Detail table** `dg2` to update to show B as belonging to A.

Can someone help to set up the onclick event which will do this?

Comment: can u post ur output (how u want ur data)... this is bit confusing..

Answer (score 0):

Try this,(onclickrow event of dg1)

```
onClickRow:function(row){

    var row = $("#dg1").datagrid('getSelected'); 
    $('#dg2').datagrid({  

     url: 'getdetaildata.action?masterid='+row.id})  

 }
```